# How right to left (RTL) google colaboratory

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Jupyter notebook can support RTL text [[see here]](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html). I want to know is there anyway to RTL text in [Google Colabolatory](https://colab.research.google.com/)? Unfortunately, there is no option in command palette to right to left text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible to edit text in right-to-left, but it's possible to display it in a result of a cell:

```
%%HTML
<div dir=rtl>
טקסט מיושר לימין, עם פסיקים וסימני שאלה. אפשרי?
</div>
```

It doesn't display correctly here on StackOverflow, but does display correctly in the cell output (i.e. after you run it) in Google Colab notebook.

Comment: How do I print a string so that it is displayed RTL? (Your example is hardcoding the RTL text, I need to feed the text from a Python variable.)

Comment: It worked for me without `%%HTML`. `%%HTML` did nothing, just appeared as a normal text in the cell.